# Where is the designer to create FKs in SSDT?

Tags: sql-server-data-tools

I've just started working with SSDT in VS 2012. From the SQL Server Object Explorer, I selected a table, right-clicked and chose View Designer. Unless I'm mistaken, the only way to create a FK is to manually enter the syntax for it in the T-SQL window at the bottom of the screen. Am I correct or is there, hopefully, a better way to do this?

BTW, when I right-click on Foreign Keys, I expected to see an add option, but all I see is this:

[image]

Comment: You should be able to right click there and choose "Add New Foreign Key". Can you add indexes or check constraints via the right click menu? How are you opening the table, from SSOX or a SSDT Project? Have you updated to the most current version? How about the SSDT Power Tools? I don't remember never being able to access that option in the right click menu, but I don't have a prior version of SSDT to test against.

Answer (score 5):

The current limit of the designer experience (as of the Dec 2012 release) for adding a foreign key is to be able to name (or rename) the key.

As @aclear16 mentions in their comment, the 'Add New Foreign Key' menu item should appear when you right-click on the 'Foreign-Keys' heading in that list.

All other changes must be done via editing in the T-SQL pane, as described in the SSDT documentation [How to: Use the Table Designer to Manage Tables and Relationships](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272680%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)